# Support Vector Regression in R: Plotting SVM model

Tags: r, plot, regression, svm

I am currently working with support vector regression and the results that the SVR achieves are very good. I think it would be nice to visualize the results and especially the model that is being build. Can you help me with an R statement that will create a plot from my svm model?

To give you an example: Assume these are my training and test sets resp.:

```
input_data <- data.frame(X = c(40,37,33,28,24,20,19,17,14,11,8,5,3,1),
    Y = c(2000,3000,4000,1300,1200,5000,3500,3400,2300,6400,1300,1200,2000,3000))
pred_data <- data.frame(X = c(23,29,17,14,12,10,9,7,5,2,1))
```

Now I create an SVM-model from that using eps-regression and a radial-kernel for the svm-function of the e1071-package:

```
svm_model <- svm(input_data$X, input_data$Y, type='eps-regression', kernel='radial')
```

...and predict the missing "Y"-value for my testset:

```
pred_data$Y <- predict(svm_model, pred_data$X)
```

I would really like to show a graph of the variable svm-model.

While looking for help online I found this little example (for a classification problem). But I could not figure out, how to adapt it to my regression problem.

```
data(iris)
model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)
plot(model, iris, Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
     slice = list(Sepal.Width = 3, Sepal.Length = 4))
```

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: So `plot(Y ~ X, data = pred_data)` didn't work?

Comment: Hi Roman, that worked but I would like to visualize the model and not the data itself.

Comment: Then use `predict` and use that instead (or in addition) of `Y`.